# Why async-await not working in this case?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, async-await

Why `async-await` not working in my case? I have a button in pageA. When it is clicked, it will pop up delete confirmation dialog.

Once the `Yes` button in confirmation dialog is clicked, it will delete data from server and return a Success code, which is 101 back to PageA.

Once the pageA receive the return value, it will refresh the `ListView`.

**PageA button**

```
onTap: () async {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  var result = await PopUpDialog().showDeleteDialog();
  if (result == 101) {
    setState(() {
      data.removeAt(index);   // remove the index in listView
    });
  } else {
    print('fjeodpedp');
  }
},
```

**PopUpDialog**

```
class PopUpDialog {
  var result;
  Future<int> showDeleteDialog() async {
         ....
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
          return AlertDialog(
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: Text('YES', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.pop(buildContext);
                    result = await _bloc.delete();   // delete server data
                    if (result == 101) {
                      return result;
                    }
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text('CANCEL'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(buildContext, rootNavigator: true)
                        .pop('dialog');
                  },
                )
              ],
              ....
        });

    return 111; 
  }
}
```

But the problem is I will get **fjeodpedp** once the delete confirmation dialog pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually pass Function parameters to my *showDialog* function, like *onYes* and *onCancel*, then call those from the *onTap* or *onPressed* events in the dialog.

Here is a functioning sample based on your original code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final int index = 5; // Sample index
  final data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; // Sample data

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Click me"),
        onPressed: () {
          showDeleteDialog(
            onYes: () { // This will be called when user taps 'YES'
              setState(() {
                data.removeAt(index); // remove the index in listView
                print("removed");
              });
            },
            onCancel: () { // This will be called when user taps 'CANCEL'
              print('fjeodpedp');
            }
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void showDeleteDialog({Function onYes, Function onCancel}) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
        return AlertDialog(
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Text('YES', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pop(buildContext);
                if (null != onYes) onYes(); // Ensure the reference exists before calling it
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text('CANCEL'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(buildContext);
                if (null != onCancel) onCancel(); // Ensure the reference exists before calling it
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

since `showDialog` is async, you `return 111` before the dialog is finished.

You can try by using `setState((){})` instead of this so it doesn't get too messy

Comment: what should I write in `setState`?

Comment: have a global variable called `result` and then set it in setState, then you can handle different values of result in your widgets.

Comment: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class 'PopUpDialog'

Answer (score 0):

You're returning 111 right after showing the dialog. Not sure what your intention was, but it seems to me that you don't need this line since you're dealing with the returned value on Page A.

Try to remove this line and see how it goes.

Comment: I have removed it but it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you did it as follows.

```
Future<int> showDeleteDialog() async {
 final response = showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
      return AlertDialog(
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Text('YES', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pop(buildContext,'yes');
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text('CANCEL'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(buildContext,'cancel');
              },
            )
          ]
      );
    }
);

  if(await response == 'yes'){
    return 101;
  }
  return 111;}
```

Comment: where should I put `result = await _bloc.delete();` ?

Comment: Within the if enter the functionality of the yes button